# React component with pressing Enter

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, components, enter

I have some react component and needed to work with "Enter" function.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount');
        document.removeEventListener('keypress', this.enter);
        document.addEventListener('keypress', this.enter.bind(this));
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('componentWillUnmount');
        document.removeEventListener('keypress', this.enter);
    }

    render() {
        return (...);
    }

    enter(target) {
        if (target.charCode === 13) {
            console.log('fired');
            /* after that component unmounted */
        }
    }
}
```

Console log show:

```
componentDidMount
fired
componentWillUnmount
```

, but when press Enter the console show again `fired`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.enter.bind(this)` returns a **new** function, which is not the same function as `this.enter`. So your `removeEventListener` is ignored, because that specific function isn't on the event list.

Remember the result of `this.enter.bind(this)` and use that when removing.

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log('componentDidMount');
    this.boundEnter = this.enter.bind(this);
    document.addEventListener('keypress', this.boundEnter);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('componentWillUnmount');
    document.removeEventListener('keypress', this.boundEnter);
}
```

(There's also no need for your `removeEventListener` in `componentDidMount`.)

Since you're using ES2015+ syntax, I'll assume you're transpiling. If you are, you could use an arrow function rather than a method for `enter`:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount');
        document.addEventListener('keypress', this.enter);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('componentWillUnmount');
        document.removeEventListener('keypress', this.enter);
    }

    render() {
        return (...);
    }

    enter = target => {
        if (target.charCode === 13) {
            console.log('fired');
            /* after that component unmounted */
        }
    };
}
```

That requires that you enable handling of [class properties](https://tc39.github.io/proposal-class-public-fields/) in your transpiler (in Babel, they're currently part of the `stage-2` preset).

Answer (score 2):

You never unbind event handler. The problem is that `this.enter.bind(this)` and `this.enter` are different functions because [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) creates new "wrapper" function from the original.

Try something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
    constructor () {
        this.enter = this.enter.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log('componentDidMount');
        document.removeEventListener('keypress', this.enter);
        document.addEventListener('keypress', this.enter);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        console.log('componentWillUnmount');
        document.removeEventListener('keypress', this.enter);
    }

    render() {
        return (...);
    }

    enter(target) {
        if (target.charCode === 13) {
            console.log('fired');
            /* after that component unmounted */
        }
    }
}
```

Note, you need to provide the *same* function to both `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener`.

Comment: Your version work, but in 'enter' needed access to this.props and this.state, that why I prefer first answer.

Comment: You can access both `this.props` and `this.state`.